# How to draw a clickable rectangle in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, events, xaml

I am an absolute beginner to WPF applications and need some help. All I’m trying to do is draw a rectangle from point A to point B, **and** be able to detect when the rectangle is clicked. So when it is clicked it turns yellow and when clicked again, red.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @John Saunders wasnt aware of that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.

1. Add a click handler to the rectangle, and toggle its color from code behind
2. Bind the rectangle's color to a View Model property, and set the property on click using a Delegate Command.

The first is easiest if you're just starting with XAML (although #2 is recommended if you want to adhere to MVVM).

```
 <Rectangle x:Name="rect" 
    Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Aquamarine" 
    MouseLeftButtonDown="Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
```

And the code-behind handler:

```
 bool toggle = false;

 private void Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {
     rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(toggle ? Colors.Aquamarine : Colors.DarkRed);
     toggle = !toggle;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. This should get me started. +1

Answer (score 6):

Use the `Rectangle` control.

```
<Rectangle
    Height="100"
    Width="100"
    MouseLeftButtonUp="Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonUp_1"
```

where `Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonUp_1` is an event handler on the containing class.

Just be aware that unless the Rectangle has a background, you'll have to click the border. The background can be white, but it does need to be specified if it's to be clickable.

Comment: Thanks for the post. It didn't go in to as mush detail as the one I marked as the answer. But it should help me get started. +1