# Is it possible to create Click event in DrawingGroup tag in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, svg, inkscape

I have converted svg files into xaml file however it says hyperlink tag is unknown using Inkscape.
I have images as:
[image: xaml images]

What I want is that every rooms should have click events.

The sample xaml code is:

```
<Grid>
<Rectangle Stretch="Fill">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <DrawingBrush>
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing><DrawingGroup x:Name="Rooms" svg:SvgObject.Id="Rooms" >
                            <DrawingGroup x:Name="lobby11" Opacity="1" svg:SvgLink.Key="lobby11" svg:SvgLink.Action="LinkNone" svg:SvgObject.Id="lobby11" svg:SvgObject.Type="Link">
                                <DrawingGroup>
                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFE6E6E6">
                                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Rect="291.682,19.979,61.042,36.067" />
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    </GeometryDrawing>
                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF000000">
                                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" Figures="M352.031,20.672L352.031,55.359 292.375,55.359 292.375,20.672 352.031,20.672 M353.418,19.285L290.988,19.285 290.988,56.743 353.418,56.743 353.418,19.285 353.418,19.285z" />
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    </GeometryDrawing>
                                </DrawingGroup>
                            </DrawingGroup>
                            <DrawingGroup x:Name="lobby12" Opacity="1" svg:SvgLink.Key="lobby12" svg:SvgLink.Action="LinkNone" svg:SvgObject.Id="lobby12" svg:SvgObject.Type="Link">
                                <DrawingGroup>
                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFE6E6E6">
                                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Rect="298.296,386.271,45.481,51.232" />
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    </GeometryDrawing>
                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF000000">
                                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" Figures="M343.261,387.255L343.261,436.527 298.813,436.527 298.813,387.255 343.261,387.255 M344.294,385.285L297.779,385.285 297.779,438.493 344.294,438.493 344.294,385.285 344.294,385.285z" />
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    </GeometryDrawing>
                                </DrawingGroup>
                            </DrawingGroup>
                        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                       </DrawingBrush>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                   </Grid>
```

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13484699/2555668

Comment: yes i tried there's no MouseLeftButtonDown event .

Comment: Try using a `Click` or `MouseLeftButtonDown` event on `Rectangle` instead, and in your `RoutedEventArgs` look at the `OriginalSource`. Also just occurred to me that every room could be a button. If you use every group separately then you don't have to worry about these things anymore.

Comment: As per MSDN documentation there not click event availabe with DrawingGroup: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawinggroup(v=vs.110).aspx